# apache server redirect request to static file passing request uri as parameter

Tags: php, angularjs, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm using apache 2.2 in centos to serve an angularjs website. There I want to allow the crawlers to read properly the meta content. For the content I've set a static php file that prints a bare html site with the required data for the crawler. 
Now my issue is to redirect the request from crawler to that file. i'm currently using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ crawler-processor.php?r=$1 [P]
```

in .htaccess but is not working. I've tried several regex combinations without luck. i'm not dealing often with apache server at this level so I assume that rule could be a little mess :)

**UPDATE:**
I've found this service http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ to test rewrite regex. Using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ crawler-processor.php?r=$1 [P]
```

it's matching properly so i'm starting to think that there is something more in the page i'm not aware of. here is the full .htaccess, maybe something is overriding the rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_HOST}/uploads/$1 [L]

# angularjs html5mode
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html

# SEO - Crawlers redirect to snapshots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ crawler-processor.php?r=$1 [P]

</IfModule>
```

apart from .htaccess, could be any specific server setting be overriding the rewrite?

**UPDATE2:**
after checking error log, seems that file being hit is not proper

```
File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/beta.host.com/httpdocs/var
```

why is getting the first folder name as filename?

Comment: And how this issue is related to angularjs?

Comment: i don't think that is an angularjs issue. i'm getting such workaround just to be sure that crawlers not processing javascript sites get the proper meta data. why do you understand i'm pointing the question to angularjs issue?

Comment: @asoriano, because you added an angularjs tag

Comment: oops sorry :) you're right. anyways if this question gets good answer it would be nice for future searchs though